# Is there a better way to writing tsql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is the query:-

```
SELECT *  FROM table 
WHERE CutOffDate > '2013-05-23 00:00:00.001'
   AND Zone = 1
  OR id IN (SELECT id FROM table 
            WHERE  Zone = 1 
               and status = 1)
```

All i need is all records greater than cutoffdate **in same Zone.** Also if any record from **same zone** has status 1. And records are from same Table.

The above query is working fine. But I am hoping there is definitely a better way to write this kind of query.

Comment: This query doesn't run fine.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: I would explicitly `CAST` the date literal to a DateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *  FROM table 
WHERE Zone = 1
AND (CutOffDate > '2013-05-23 00:00:00.001' OR status = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by ***Same Zone*** ?   the Same as what ??  The way the query is written it appears you mean Zone 1.

If so, then you have over complicated it. I believe you might try

```
SELECT *  FROM table 
WHERE Zone = 1
  And (status = 1 Or  CutOffDate 
        > '2013-05-23 00:00:00.001')
```

Comment: So do I, you can probably tell. I answer earlier but ... (sour grapes)

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite it like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM table
WHERE CutOffDate > '2013-05-23 00:00:00.001'
AND (
    Zone = 1
    OR
    Status = 1
)
```

But I guess your original query isn"t really doing what you expect it to do...

EDIT: Just in case you actually figure your query doesn't do the job, this one might:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM table AS T1
WHERE T1.CutOffDate > '2013-05-23 00:00:00.001'
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP(1)
        1
    FROM table AS T2
    WHERE T2.Zone = T1.Zone
    AND T2.Status = 1
)
```

Comment: How would this check for "any record from same zone has status 1" ?

Answer (score 0):

After the cutoff date, or a row with status 1 in the same zone:

```
SELECT  *  
FROM    YourTable yt1
WHERE   CutOffDate > '2013-05-23 00:00:00.001'
        OR EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    YourTable yt2
        WHERE   yt1.Zone = yt2.Zone
                AND yt2.status = 1
        )
```

If that's not what you looking for, please clarify your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM [table] 
    WHERE Zone = 1
        AND
           (CutOffDate > '2013-05-23 00:00:00.001'
            OR  status = 1)
```

This is the same as the query in your question. I can't really tell what you mean other than that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `id` is unique in the original table, then your logic is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE (CutOffDate > '2013-05-23 00:00:00.001' AND Zone = 1)
      or (zone = 1 and status = 1);
```

You can further simplify this to:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE zone = 1 and
       (CutOffDate > '2013-05-23 00:00:00.001' or status = 1);
```

If id is not unique, then your query is a good way of doing what you need.  Alternatively, you could phrase the query using window functions.

Comment: Wrong. That's not how precedence occur.

Comment: @Serge . . . `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`.  This is how the `where` clause is interpreted.  Here is Microsoft's description, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186992(v=sql.105).aspx.  I think every other database would have a similar description.